# Knockout binding provider preprocessor with ko:if binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've been playing around with using Knockout's `bindingProvider` API to bind custom elements, just as an experiment really, and to see if I can make templates a bit more readable.

My processor is in general working fine, at least for most bindings, but for the if binding, it doesn't work.

The markup is:

```
<k-o text="Text" click="clickHandler"></k-o>

<k-o if="IsShowing"><!-- Doesn't work -->
  <p>
    Hello 1!
  </p>
</k-o>

<span data-bind="if: IsShowing"><!-- Works -->
  <p>
    Hello 2!
  </p>
</span>
```

And the code is:

```
ko.bindingProvider.instance.preprocessNode = function(node) 
{
    if (node.nodeName == 'K-O') 
    {
        var el = document.createElement('span');      
        var att = document.createAttribute('data-bind');

      var attvals = [];

      for(var i = 0; i < node.attributes.length; i++)
        attvals.push(node.attributes[i].name + ': ' + node.attributes[i].value);

      att.value = attvals.join(', ');
        el.setAttributeNode(att);

      node.parentNode.replaceChild(el, node);

      return el;
    }
}
```

Demo Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/whelkaholism/wzqL64ga/

So the text binding and click binding work fine, but although if I check the object inspector and the generated nodes for the if are identical to the hardcoded ones, only the hardcoded ones work.

(This use case for this is for backend database access applications, making functional templates clearer in development. Any SEO or related issues of custom elements are not relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just forgotten one thing:

```
el.innerHTML = node.innerHTML;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wzqL64ga/8/

Comment: Ahahaha! Brilliant, so obvious I couldn't see it! Thanks, you're a star.